# How do i get my keystroke typed in searchbox?

Tags: rpa, workfusion

When i have coded for typing(keystroke) , the code gets struck especially when it is in the loop. It doesn't type the expected keystroke.

For instance, When it is time to filter in excel after going to a particular column and after giving alt+down, I gave mouse click,e and also tab for moving to the search field, it moves but it does not type in the desired character. It either moves out of the filter and types or doesn't type at all.

And also, while executing goto command, it throws error while it has to type in the keystroke,

This case happens mostly during the second execution of the for the loop. (First time in most cases goes on well).

for...
      .......
      enter keystroke(ctrl + g)
      enter keystroke(AW1)
      enter keystroke(enter) 
      ...............

It doesn't type in the desired keystroke at serach box especially during  second time execution of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to the Search field using Window action before typing there.